# NPM Keeps Having Issues Finding My Node Path

Tags: node.js, npm, nowjs-sockets

Here's an example for me trying to install Node-Proxy because NowJS needs it:

sudo npm install node-proxy

```
    > node-proxy@0.5.2 install /home/jennifer/node_modules/node-proxy
    > make

    BUILDING: C++ Component
    Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++ 
    Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
    Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
    Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
    Checking for g++                         : ok  
    Checking for node path                   : not found 
    Checking for node prefix                 : ok /usr/local 
    'configure' finished successfully (0.034s)
    Waf: Entering directory `/home/jennifer/node_modules/node-proxy/src/build'
    no such environment: default
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/local/bin/node-waf", line 16, in <module>
        Scripting.prepare(t, os.getcwd(), VERSION, wafdir)
      File "/usr/local/bin/../lib/node/wafadmin/Scripting.py", line 145, in prepare
        prepare_impl(t, cwd, ver, wafdir)
      File "/usr/local/bin/../lib/node/wafadmin/Scripting.py", line 135, in prepare_impl
        main()
      File "/usr/local/bin/../lib/node/wafadmin/Scripting.py", line 188, in main
        fun(ctx)
      File "/usr/local/bin/../lib/node/wafadmin/Scripting.py", line 386, in build
        return build_impl(bld)
      File "/usr/local/bin/../lib/node/wafadmin/Scripting.py", line 399, in build_impl
        bld.add_subdirs([os.path.split(Utils.g_module.root_path)[0]])
      File "/usr/local/bin/../lib/node/wafadmin/Build.py", line 981, in add_subdirs
        self.recurse(dirs, 'build')
      File "/usr/local/bin/../lib/node/wafadmin/Utils.py", line 634, in recurse
        f(self)
      File "/home/jennifer/node_modules/node-proxy/src/wscript", line 13, in build
        obj = bld.new_task_gen('cxx', 'shlib', 'node_addon')
      File "/usr/local/bin/../lib/node/wafadmin/Build.py", line 335, in new_task_gen
        ret = cls(*k, **kw)
      File "/usr/local/bin/../lib/node/wafadmin/Tools/ccroot.py", line 162, in __init__
        TaskGen.task_gen.__init__(self, *k, **kw)
      File "/usr/local/bin/../lib/node/wafadmin/TaskGen.py", line 118, in __init__
        self.env = self.bld.env.copy()
    AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'copy'
    cp: cannot stat `src/build/*/node-proxy.node': No such file or directory
    make: *** [all] Error 1
    npm ERR! error installing node-proxy@0.5.2 Error: node-proxy@0.5.2 install: `make`
    npm ERR! error installing node-proxy@0.5.2 `sh "-c" "make"` failed with 2
    npm ERR! error installing node-proxy@0.5.2     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/exec.js:49:20)
    npm ERR! error installing node-proxy@0.5.2     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:67:17)
    npm ERR! error installing node-proxy@0.5.2     at ChildProcess.onexit (child_process.js:192:12)
    npm ERR! node-proxy@0.5.2 install: `make`
    npm ERR! `sh "-c" "make"` failed with 2
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Failed at the node-proxy@0.5.2 install script.
    npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the node-proxy package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.
    npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
    npm ERR!     make
    npm ERR! You can get their info via:
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls node-proxy
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! System Linux 2.6.38-11-generic
    npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "node-proxy"
    npm ERR! cwd /home/jennifer/node_modules
    npm ERR! node -v v0.4.11
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.30
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /home/jennifer/node_modules/npm-debug.log
    npm not ok
```

Answer (score 3):

Seems like this issue has also been reported here:
https://github.com/joyent/node/issues/1716

The solution is here: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.lang.javascript.nodejs/29563

Comment: sqlite3 on Ubuntu 10.10 fails too with the same "no such environment: default" and what is mentioned in the link works!

Answer (score 2):

I got this when trying to downgrade from node v0.6x to v0.4x. Fix was to run `sudo make uninstall` in the v0.6x directory and then reinstall v0.4x.

Comment: I am using nodev0.8.21,I tried with sudo make uninstall & sudo make install in node directory, but no effect.